# How to stop a page from returning a 500 error

Tags: php

I have a basic PHP script.

```
$hike_id = $_REQUEST['hike_id'];
$height = $_REQUEST['height'];
$width = $_REQUEST['width'];
```

Sometimes these are no such parameters passed into the request and I am guessing that is why the 500 error is being returned.

Is there a way to stop that page from returning the 500 error somehow?  Here is an example of it:
http://comehike.com/outdoors/hike_widget.php?hike_id=164&height=700&width=500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just conditionally assign the variables using ternary expressions and `isset()`:

```
$hike_id = isset($_REQUEST['hike_id']) ? $_REQUEST['hike_id'] : 0;
$height = isset($_REQUEST['height']) ? $_REQUEST['height'] : 0;
$width = isset($_REQUEST['width']) ? $_REQUEST['width'] : 0;
```

Also, if these parameters are always coming in in the query string like you said, you are better off using `$_GET` than `$_REQUEST`

Comment: ah so is the error happening because I am trying to assign some value which doesn't exist to the variables?

Comment: Yes, Also, it sounds like you have your display_errors turned off in php.ini. with that turned on you would have seen an error message like "undefined index 'height'"

Answer (score 1):

```
$hike_id = isset($_REQUEST['hike_id']) ? $_REQUEST['hike_id'] : '0';
```

Comment: If `$_REQUEST['hike_id']` exists it sets `$hike_id` to that, otherwise it sets it to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()` to check variable is set

Comment: Its way to handle varible. Sorry but i didint get any 500 error. If you say exactly when you get that error, we can help maybe

Comment: that page shows up in my Google Webmaster tools as having a 500 error...I myself don't understand why :)

Comment: I do use isset later in the code, but I am just not sure why the 500 error would happen. I figured it was those variables.